# Get Uploaded Video Status after it's been Processed

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I am uploading a video to Youtube server-side.

I understand the order of the statuses: uploaded -> processed -> rejected

I need to get the "rejected" which could take several seconds to several minutes to reach that status depending on the size of the video file.

So, how can I delay my script, preferably without using `sleep(300)` since it's not very accurate and also seems to be sleeping the ENTIRE website?

This script is running in the background via command line.

I snipped the script just because it's the standard resumable upload script which can be found on the YouTube API v3 website.

```
------------ SNIPPED -------------

# Create a video insert request
$insert_response = $youtube_service->videos->insert("status,snippet", $google_video, array('mediaUpload' => $media_file_upload));

$upload_status = FALSE;

# Read file and upload chunk by chunk
$handle = fopen($video_path, "rb");
while(!$upload_status && !feof($handle))
{
    $chunk = fread($handle, $chunk_size_bytes);
    $upload_status = $media_file_upload->nextChunk($insert_response, $chunk);
}

fclose($handle);

sleep(300);

$to='somebody@domain.com;'
$reply_to='server@domain.com';
$subject='Video status from domain.com';
$body='';

# Check the video status.
$video_id=random_YouTube_ID;
$check_status=$youtube_service->videos->listVideos($video_id, 'status', array('id' => $video_id));

# Check if the uploaded video status is rejected.
if($check_status['items'][0]['status']['uploadStatus']=="rejected")
{
    # Delete video file from server and database entry here.

    # Check if the rejection status was a duplicate.
    if($check_status['items'][0]['status']['rejectionReason']=="duplicate")
    {
        # Tell the user the video was a duplicate.
        $body.='Your video was rejected because it was a duplicate video';
    }
}
elseif($check_status['items'][0]['status']['uploadStatus']=="processed")
{
    # Tell the user the video was uploaded and processed but has no been accepted or rejected at this time.
    $body.='Your video has been uploaded to YouTube and processed but has not been accepted or rejected at this time';
}
elseif($check_status['items'][0]['status']['uploadStatus']=="uploaded")
{
    # Tell the user the video has been uploaded but not processed at this time.
    $body.='Your video has been uploaded to YouTube but has not been processed at this time.';
}

$mail=new Email();
$mail->sendEmail($subject, $to, $body, $reply_to);
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: did you get your answer?

Comment: @Bik I ended up running a cron every hour or something like that (can't remember exactly how often it runs).

Comment: Thanks For Reply. I am trying for two days and can't find any solution for this...... Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30344069/youtube-php-api-check-video-is-duplicate-or-not